# Como puedo filtrar estos items?

Tags: reactjs

Buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente problema y es que estoy intentando filtrar unos items y no lo estoy logrando.

La funcion de esto seria la siguiente:

Tengo un header con checkboxes que son las categorias, pero, lo que necesito es que no se muestren todas las categorias, sino solamente las que se estan usando.

Entonces tengo por aqui el objeto que trae todas las categorias de la API
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito seria aplicando un `filter()` filtrar estas categorias para que solo se muestren las que tambien estan en este `array` que es el que trae las categorias usadas.

```
["3D", "VR", "Audio-Visual", "WebGL", "Sound", "Physics", "AI", "2D"]
```

Intente algo como esto basandome en otro filter que habia hecho para otra cosa en el sitio pero de nada me sirvio.

```js
getTags() {
  fetch(backend()+'/api/tags', {
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(result => result.json())
   .then(tags => {this.setState({tags});
          var arr = [];
          var backup = this.state.categories;

      for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            arr.push(this.state.tags[i].name)
        }

            tags = this.uniqueArray(arr);

            const categories = backup.filter(cat => {
            const _tags = tags
            const hasTags = _tags.filter(tag => tags.includes(tag));
            if (hasTags.length) {
              return cat;
            }
          });
          this.setState({categories});

   });
 }
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: No termino de entender. Dices que tienes un array con las categorías usadas, entonces, ¿quieres que se haga un filtrado a los ítems para mostrar aquellos que estén tageados con las categorías usadas solamente?

Comment: Exacto querido, eso mismo. Mostrar solo las que esten usando los demos tu que conoces mi proyecto

Comment: Un tag es un objeto, cuál es la propiedad que tiene **el nombre de la categoría**? ¿`.name`?

Comment: Solo te bastaría una línea: `allTags.filter(tag => usedTags.includes(tag.name));`.

Comment: Si, seria .name, intentare con eso a ver que tal

Comment: Perfecto colega, si deseas publicalo como respuesta y te califico

Comment: Listo hermano. Hace días no me conecto al skype, en unos días me conecto que estoy en unos asuntillos. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sabiendo que:

- Tienes un array de **objetos** tags, que representan a todos los tags.
- Tienes un array con los **nombres** de los tags usados.

Solo hace hacer un filtrado básico:

```
allTags.filter(tag => usedTags.includes(tag.name));
```